# MySQL deadlocking on single-column table batch INSERT during transaction

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I've been trying to work around this but haven't found a way besides retrying, which is inefficient for what should be a fairly simple, high-concurrency operation.

I have an InnoDB table on a MySQL 5.6/5.7 DB that has two columns... `id` + another column (with a **unique** index). During a transaction, I do a batch `SELECT` on this table, and then `INSERT` the missing rows thereafter. **However,** it's deadlocking due to activity in other simultaneous transactions.

Is there a solution? I've tried setting the transaction mode to `READ COMMITTED` without seeing any difference.